# Calendar navigation in PHP (by week)

Tags: php, calendar, strtotime

I'm building a calendar which also displays a one week "view".

Having some trouble with the "last week" and "next week" nav...

Here's what I've got:

```
/*
   Date to calc the start and end of week.
   $thisYear, $thisMonth, $thisDay are passed in
*/

$combineDate = $thisYear . "-" . $thisMonth . "-" . $thisDay . " 00:00:00";
//$timeString = strtotime($combineDate); (tried with this format, but same result)

//calculate last week's date
$lastWeek_year = date('Y',strtotime("$combineDate -1 week"));
$lastWeek_month = date('n',strtotime("$combineDate -1 week"));
$lastWeek_day = date('j',strtotime("$combineDate -1 week"));

//calculate next week's date
$nextWeek_year = date('Y',strtotime("$combineDate +1 week"));
$nextWeek_month = date('n',strtotime("$combineDate +1 week"));
$nextWeek_day = date('j',strtotime("$combineDate +1 week"));

[links look like this:]
//last week
<a href="$currentPage?day=$lastWeek_day&month=$lastWeek_month&year=$lastWeek_year">

//next week
<a href="$currentPage?day=$nextWeek_day&month=$nextWeek_month&year=$nextWeek_year">
```

Works beautifully for the current month and next month as the end of October (2015) and beginning of November fall on a Saturday and Sunday (respectively)!

But it breaks in December, because the 1st is a Tuesday (doh!)

And it breaks when going from 2015 to 2016..

I've tried several different approaches using strtotime...

Anyone got a clean solution?

Many thanks!

Comment: For clarification: the above function has a date string passed into it (YYYY, MM, DD).  From that, I am building a one week calendar. So I need to calculate the date (YYYY, MM, DD) for the first day of the week (Sunday) and the date for the last day of the week (Saturday).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I used the following:

```
$date = date_create('2000-01-01');
date_add($date, date_interval_create_from_date_string('10 days'));
echo date_format($date, 'Y-m-d');
```

Comment: That doesn't seem like it would work very well.  My code above works in PHP 5.6 (although PHP seems to consider Monday as the first day of the week).

Comment: Thanks, but the above 3 lines can be used to output any date string that I need. Basically it is your answer (as I am using the DateTime object)...

Comment: You're just adding 10 days so that 2000-01-01 (Saturday) + 10 days= 2000-01-11.  You'd actually pass by one whole Monday and land on a Tuesday.

That doesn't seem to match the problem you described.

Comment: sure, I change the date string from '10 days' to '1 days' (etc) to match what I needed. My point was that I only needed those three lines of code to get the results I was looking for. Thanks for the tip about the datetime object.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you're wanting?  The date of the Monday of both the last week and the next week?  The Sunday?  Do you have the DateTime object?  Does this work?

```
$date = new DateTime(NULL);

$datey = new DateTime(); $date = $date->setDate($thisYear, $thisMonth, $thisDay)->setTime(0, 0);
$beginLastWeek = $datey->setTimestamp(strtotime("this week", $date->sub(new DateInterval("P1W"))->getTimestamp()))
    ->sub(new DateInterval('P1D'));
$datex = new DateTime(); $date = $date->setDate($thisYear, $thisMonth, $thisDay)->setTime(0, 0);
$beginNextWeek = $datex->setTimestamp(strtotime("this week", $date->add(new DateInterval("P1W"))->getTimestamp()))
    ->sub(new DateInterval('P1D'));

list($lastWeek_year, $lastWeek_month, $lastWeek_day) =
    explode(":", $beginLastWeek->format("Y:m:d"));
list($nextWeek_year, $nextWeek_month, $nextWeek_day) =
    explode(":", $beginNextWeek->format("Y:m:d"));

print "$lastWeek_year-$lastWeek_month-$lastWeek_day\n";
print "$nextWeek_year-$nextWeek_month-$nextWeek_day\n";
```

The above code should in theory work on PHP 5.3 and treats Sunday as the beginning of the week and given 2001-01-01 you'd get:

Last week start date: 2000-12-24
Next week start date: 2001-01-07

Answer (score 0):

This might be useful in this scenario. It wraps core PHP DateTime class and exposes  methods like nextDay, previousDay, nextMonth. So its really easy to navigate through date by day(s), month(s), year(s).

https://packagist.org/packages/ishworkh/navigable-date

For eg.

```
$daysInAWeek = 7;

$DateNow = \NavigableDate\NavigableDateFacade::create('2017-02-23');

echo 'Current Date --> ' . $DateNow->format('Y-m-d') . PHP_EOL;

$DateAfterAWeek = $DateNow->daysAfter($daysInAWeek);
echo 'Date After a week --> ' . $DateAfterAWeek->format('Y-m-d') . PHP_EOL;

$DateBeforeAWeek = $DateNow->daysAfter(-$daysInAWeek);
echo 'Date before a week --> ' . $DateBeforeAWeek->format('Y-m-d') . PHP_EOL;
```

gives

`Current Date --> 2017-02-23
   Date After a week --> 2017-03-02 
   Date before a week --> 2017-02-16`

And likewise,

method takes in resetTime boolean value which decides if the time has to      be set to 00:00:00

```
$PrevDay = $DateAfterAWeek->previousDay(false);
echo 'Date before a day of next week date --> ' . $PrevDay->format('Y-m-d') . PHP_EOL;
```

gives

`Date before a day from next week date --> 2017-03-01`

Each method returns an instance of `NavigableDate`. So you can chain the methods on date return by any of the method. One thing to notice is navigate methods has reset* params which, by its name, resets time to 00:00:00 or days to 1, first of the month. For more info on this, plz visit,
https://packagist.org/packages/ishworkh/navigable-date

Comment: Instead of just pasting the link if you could elaborate your answer with some code example/snippet using the package you've mentioned would be much more helpful.